# DOMPDF output not the same between localhost and web server

Tags: html, codeigniter, dompdf

I just successfully used the dompdf function library in our application. I have no problem the way it works in the localhost, I was able to make my own design html view to be converted as a pdf, with color blue headers and a table formatted output using html table tag. However, when I uploaded the files in our web server, it returns a different output not the same in the localhost. Although it returns an output, the headers have no color anymore and the table format disappear. Can anyone help to figure out and solve this problem? Thank you very much. Below shows the output in localhost and server
[image: localhost output here]

[image]

Comment: i think DOMpdf might have a problem accessing the stylesheets. make sure you have set the permissions on your webserver right

Comment: If you uploaded from your local system to the server it's possible the path information has changed. This all depends on how you are loading your document into dompdf and how the stylesheets are referenced. Also, which version of dompdf?

Comment: I tried to used internal css instead and it works now..it is the external css that was not accessed.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the head section of your page that would help a lot.

If you're on windows: locally there's no difference in capital letters or not. But online it does matter. So check if the